# Searching Multi Path or Twig Queries in a dictionary object

Tags: c#, xml, string, search, xpath

I've to implement a similar functionality like `XPath` by reading the `XML` file and saving it in some object. I've used dictionary for this purpose.

The XML file is read and saved in a dictionary object with keys as unique paths from root to leaf nodes and the values are some specific numbers separated by commas. So the dictionary keys and values are both of type String.

Searching for the single Path queries like `/bookstore/book/author` is easier as only one entry with this specific key can be found in the dictionary.

What is the best way to search for multipath or twig queries in this dictionary object? A sample query can be `//book//last-name`.

I've to search all the paths that satisfied the above query along with the count of comma separated values in the dictionary object.

A sample XML file is shown below

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database --> 
<bookstore> 
    <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0"> 
        <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title> 
        <author> 
            <first-name>Benjamin</first-name> 
            <last-name>Franklin</last-name> 
        </author> 
        <price>8.99</price> 
    </book> 
    <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967" ISBN="0-201-63361-2"> 
        <title>The Confidence Man</title> 
        <author> 
            <first-name>Herman</first-name> 
            <last-name>Melville</last-name> 
        </author> 
        <price>11.99</price> 
    </book> 
    <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991" ISBN="1-861001-57-6"> 
        <title>The Gorgias</title> 
        <author> 
            <name>Plato</name> 
        </author> 
        <price>9.99</price> 
    </book> 
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary of absolute XPaths and you want to match `//book//last-name`, you will need to perform 3 steps:

1) iterate all the keys in your dictionary and reduce them to a set of keys which contain `/book`, lets call that `set2`.

2) iterate all keys in `set2` and reduce them to a set of keys which contain `/last-name`, lets call that `set3`.

3) Retrieve all entries from your original dictionary which are in `set3` and you have your answer.

Comment: This means I've to make the number of sets equals to the number of // present in the query?                                     What about the twig?                                                               I need to know also the fastest way of searching and retrieving. Do I've to use regular expression or some string matching function can be used efficiently?

Comment: In the mechanism I described, the number of sets would be equal to the number of steps in your XPath. I cannot tell you which is the fastest mechanism, you have given me no information about your input data or the programming language that you are implementing this in. You have chosen to use a `dictionary` type, so I assume that will dictate your performance. If you just want to do this quickly, I would suggest that if you have lots of data then to load this into a Native XML Database such as eXist, and let that execute your XPath.

Comment: Thanks and sorry not to mention the language in the main subject. I'm using C# which is in keywords. I'm trying to evaluate the performance of query processing without using XPath.